# django-admin --version can not find installed version

Tags: python3, django

I have installed latest `django`(2.2) using `pip3` command. Although it is successfully installed I getting below error for the command-

```
django-admin --version
Error:  Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django.
Same error I am getting while going to create a project using start project.
```

I have also tried to solve this problem after seeing some similar question in this platform by installing `django` with `apt-get` command, but it installs `django` 1.1 not 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

One reason you cannot find the Django is because you installed it in one virtual environment and now looking for it in another place.So suppose you are in the directory `Codes`. 
`$ cd Codes`

Then first you create a virtual environment:

```
$ virtualenv env
```

Then you activate the virtual environment:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
```

Once activated, your terminal will look like this: `(env) $`
Now install django inside `env`:

```
(env) $ pip install django
```

SO you have `Django` INSIDE THIS `env`, each time you want django, you need to activate this `env`. So suppose, you close this terminal and open a new terminal:

Then you 1st activate the environment:

```
$ cd Codes
$ source env/bin/activate     # <--- do this whenever you need django
(env)$ django-admin --version 
2.2.7 # <---  django version
```

I hope this works.

Comment: I did not create any virtual environment. I installed it globally from root